# MariaDB version 10.5.9 unable to install

Tags: database, mariadb

In my current workplace we are using MariaDB version 10.5.9 for our DB's and we are trying to reinstall this version for testing purposes on a separate container. However, seems anything from 10.5.9 below is failing with the follow error;

```
root@mdb-10-5:~# curl -LsS https://r.mariadb.com/downloads/mariadb_repo_setup | sudo bash -s -- --mariadb-server-version=mariadb-10.5.9
# [info] Checking for script prerequisites.
# [warning] Found existing file at /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mariadb.list. Moving to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mariadb.list.old_5
# [error] MariaDB Server version 10.5.9 is not working.
#         Please verify that the version is correct.
#
#         The latest MariaDB Server versions are:
#             10.10.1 10.3.36 10.4.26 10.5.17 10.6.10 10.7.6 10.8.5 10.9.3
#
#         More information on MariaDB releases is available at:
#             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/release-notes/
```

When I try the same command with version 10.5.10, it works and downloads successfully.

I am using the following procedure, one of which is the MariaDB KB:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-package-repository-setup-and-usage/

https://www.dbi-services.com/blog/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-mariadb/

Both guides use the same repo, and it is also the only thing that I have found specific when I search for information to install this particular version or MariaDB.

Can anyone offer any suggestions or have experienced similar problems?

Comment: If you are asking about MariaDB, please don't tag your question with 'mysql'. MariaDB and MySQL are different products.

Comment: We (MariaDB corporation) recently moved over our repositories to a content delivery network instead of using our own servers only.

Unfortunately the new service does not have a full archive of older releases yet, the oldest 10.5 we have on there for example is 10.5.10.

I have filed an internal bug report / feature request about that already, but it is still pending. 

Give me an hour and I will try to dig up an older version of mariadb_repo_setup that still creates repo files for the old repo server, which still exists  ... or at least a mariadb.list file with the old servers repo URLs

Comment: Just out of curiosity: is there a specific reason for using such a rather old minor release (from Feb 22, 2021)?

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for the suggestion and for fixing the tags.

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe I do understand that it is an older release, however, it's the current version we have across all DBs

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe also we discussed in upgrading to to 10.5.10 since its easier accessible to install that version from the repo

Answer (score 1):

We (MariaDB corporation) recently moved over our repositories to a content delivery network instead of using our own servers only. Unfortunately the new service does not have a full archive of older releases yet, the oldest 10.5 we have on there for example is 10.5.10.

I have filed an internal bug report / feature request about that already, but it is still pending.

Meanwhile you can "fix" this by first running the repo setup script with a supported version like 10.5.10, and then editing the repository file it created, replacing the version number with 10.5.9, and the host name `dlm.mariadb.com` with `download.mariadb.com`.

On Debian and Ubuntu the repository file would be `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mariadb.list`, and you'd have to run `apt-get update` afterwards to pick up the repo change before installing packages.

On RHEL, CentOS, Rocky etc. the file is `/etc/yum.repos.d/mariadb.repo` and no further action is needed before installing actual packages.

Comment: @Harmut, Thanks for your recommendation. Everything works fine until the `apt-get update` step. It seems like the repository key is not signed. Do I need some specific key download before I can run the update and installation process?

E: Failed to fetch https://download.mariadb.com/repo/mariadb-server/10.5.9/repo/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  520   [IP: 104.18.135.24 443]
E: The repository 'https://download.mariadb.com/repo/mariadb-server/10.5.9/repo/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.

Comment: Same problem with dlm.mariadb.com but the alternatives at download.mariadb.com have also been removed

Comment: Seems the new location is for example: https://dlm.mariadb.com/browse/mariadb_server/163/1546/repo/debian/

Comment: Simply unusable, had to find a mirror: http://digitaloceanmirrors.com/mariadb/repo/10.6/debian