# Install MariaDB 10.5 on Ubuntu 20.04: Could not import signing key

Tags: ubuntu, installation, mariadb

I am trying to install MariaDB 10.5 on my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop.

I have downloaded the tar from [the download page](https://mariadb.com/downloads/).  The tar turned out to contain the deb files rather than the actual code, and it had a README file with directions which instructed me to run `setup_repository` script included in the distribution.

Running this script returned the following error:

gpg: can't open 'MariaDB-C74CD1D8-public.asc': No such file or directory

I have found a [MariaDB page on the gpg keys](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/gpg/) which suggested running

```
sudo curl -LsSo /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mariadb-keyring-2019.gpg https://supplychain.mariadb.com/mariadb-keyring-2019.gpg
```

However, this did not help.

Any other suggestion?

Many thanks!

Note: this question has been closed as a duplicate of [another question on difficulties in installing a specific version of MariaDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73988085/mariadb-version-10-5-9-unable-to-install).  However, the difficulty of this other question is completely different, and StackOverflow did not suggest it to me as a possible duplicate when I formulated my original question.  Besides, the answer I have received to my question, is much more detailed and helpful that the answer to the other question.  (I am still to try this answer.)  Thus, it would be helpful to keep my question for other users.  So please do not close it.

Comment: An additional reason to keep this question is that the search for the error message I received, did not yield anything relevant.

Comment: This question will remain closed since it is off-topic here, even without being a duplicate. SO is only for _programming_ questions. This might be on topic at [su], [sf], or [unix.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a less "download a script and install option", MariaDB Foundation does do releases and exposes a repository.

There's a [download repo tool](https://mariadb.org/download/?t=repo-config&d=20.04+%22focal%22&v=10.5) that shows the configuration.

As root:

```
$ mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
$ curl -o /etc/apt/keyrings/mariadb-keyring.pgp 'https://mariadb.org/mariadb_release_signing_key.pgp'
$ cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mariadb.sources
# MariaDB 10.5 repository list - created 2023-09-05 22:32 UTC
# https://mariadb.org/download/
X-Repolib-Name: MariaDB
Types: deb
URIs: https://deb.mariadb.org/10.5/ubuntu
Suites: focal
Components: main main/debug
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/mariadb-keyring.pgp

(ctrl-D)
$ apt-get update && apt-get install mariadb-server
```